# Implementation of has_member_function

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template-meta-programming

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/6949852
I learned how to check whether a member function exists, then I re-write it to standardize the codes:

Now the codes become:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A  //has hello
{
  void hello() {}
};

struct B {}; //no hello

template<typename T>
struct has_hello
{
private:
  using yes = char;
  using no = long;
  template<typename C>
  static yes has(decltype(&C::hello));
  template<typename C>
  static no has(...);
public:
  enum name : bool {value = std::is_same<decltype(has<T>(nullptr)), yes>::value};
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type<has_hello<A>::name>::type>(has_hello<A>::value) << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast<std::underlying_type<has_hello<B>::name>::type>(has_hello<B>::value) << std::endl;
}
```

Compared to original codes:

1. 0 -> `nullptr`
2. enum -> enum name : type
3. sizeof -> is_same
4. typeof -> decltype

Comment: It would be great to keep updates invisible, e.g. just don't mention anything happened. CR focuses on reviewing particular version of the code, and it becomes harder if the target is moving. You can add more tests/docs/explanation if you'd like though.

Comment: @Incomputable Ok, thx

Comment: I recommend you to hold on with accepting an answer, as it discourages other people from posting their answers. Usually 1-2 days if wait time is enough.

Comment: @Incomputable Yes, what you said is reasonable, thx again

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Old technique

The version you're using relies on overload resolution. The current form of detection idiom relies on SFINAE. <s>IIRC SFINAE didn't exist pre-C++11.</s>(Thanks to @JDlugosz)

### Code Review

- Inherit from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`

  That will spare a lot of boilerplate, and incorporates with tag dispatch quite well. It might not be directly usable in your case without some indirection and hiding into `namespace detail`.
- Don't use `enum` as a member where `static constexpr bool` will do

  Even though with freestanding values it is a different story due to linkage. `bool` will just bring less surprises.
- Provide `xxx_v` value aliases

### Somewhat modern approach

Lets take somewhat more interesting example.

> Identify if value of type `Element` can be `push_back`ed into container of type `Container`.

Today, it is suggested to first "carve out" the operation itself into an alias:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
using pushback_t = decltype(std::declval<Container>().push_back(std::declval<Element>()));
```

Then, `std::void_t` is used:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct has_pushback : std::false_type{};

template <typename Container, typename Element>
struct has_pushback<Container, Element, std::void_t<pushback_t<Container, Element>>>:
                        std::true_type{};
```

And then `_v` value alias is provided:

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
inline constexpr bool has_pushback_v = has_pushback<Container, Element>::value;
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7H3h17Eb6CIu0dua).

*Shameless self PR*: if you're a bit confused about how SFINAE works in the new version, I recommend reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051415/why-doesnt-compiler-prompt-double-definition-when-using-detection-idiom) which I've asked in the past.

### Better upgrade path

When `std::is_detected` will arrive, one can easily put something like this (provided a copy the operation alias from above):

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
struct has_pushback : std::is_detected<pushback_t, Container, Element>
{};
```

That will spare even more boilerplate. See comments for already existing implementations.

Comment: Thx for your answer I'll try these approach after my ddl today

Comment: ⟪IIRC SFINAE didn't exist pre-C++11.⟫  It most certainly did!  I think you are thinking of **expression** SFINAE, in the body of a `decltype` unevaluated expression.

Comment: "when it will arrive…"  see [my file](https://github.com/jdlugosz/d3/blob/master/include/d3/portability/is_detected.h) to use in the mean time.

Comment: Consider adding that this tests for the existence of a single lone member with the name, instead of at least one.